# I need an adapter for a 9-circuit/2-row dual USB computer cable from 0.1" to 2 mm pitch

Tags: connector, adapter

Consider the (female) connectors in following photo:

[image]

On the left hand is a (sort of) typical PC case power switch connector (the braided cable goes to the actual switch. On the right hand is another connector, which has 6 wires connecting to it, from a small-form-factor case for a small motherboard (Asrock X300M-STX). An image of the motherboard is attached further below.

But - this is not a question about computers! It's a question about wire connectors. My problem is that the motherboard's connector for this wire is narrower than is customary in other PCs (i.e. shorter distance between pin holes); but I'm switching cases, and my new case has standard-size connectors (like the 2-pin one in the photo) - and I can't fit the standard-size connectors onto the narrow headers - it's too big, and the pins get deformed.

So, my question is: Are there some kind of standard(ish) parts I could use to form some adapter between my smaller-size header pins and the normal-size connectors? or the other way around? I am trying to avoid any soldering if possible...

How can I adapt the header of pins on the board to take regular connectors like I have for the power switch?

**Edit**: Some dimensions:

9-pin connector: 10mm x 4mm overall, about 2mm between centers of each hole.

2-pin power switch connector: 5mm x 2mm, about 2.5mm between centers of holes.

Comment: Could you make a few measurements of the bigger and the smaller ones?  It's much easier with a few numbers to give good advice.

Comment: What do you mean by "narrower"? What is more narrow? Do you mean "a smaller pitch? If you mean pitch, what is the pitch of the female plug (pictured) and when is the pitch of the PCB header on the motherboard (not pictured). Standard pitches are 2 mm and 2.54 mm.

Comment: @jonathanjo: Added measurements.

Comment: @DavideAndrea: See edit.

Comment: I really wish you had asked your actual question instead of rambling on about unrelated matters. I edited your post to ask the actual question. Feel free to edit your text accordingly.

Comment: @DavideAndrea : Thanks for the edit. As you may have noticed, I am a newbie in this particular community.

Answer (score 1):

> I need an adapter for a 9-circuit/2-row dual USB computer cable from 0.1" to 2 mm pitch

1. https://www.google.com/search?q=adapter+for+a+9-circuit%2F2-row+dual+USB+computer+cable+from+0.1%22+to+2+mm+pitch
2. [https://www.amazon.com/2-54mm-header-adapter-Serial-length/dp/B00DBIHE2A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DBIHE2A)
3. Seller: https://e-itx.com/2-54mm-to-2-0mm-pitch-pin-header-adapter-cable-for-pc-serial-port-3-inch-length/

[image: adapter for a 9-circuit-2-row dual USB cable]

{Amazon}

Comment: So, this is great! ... and if I were in the US, I would just order it. Of course, that's none of your fault, but - getting it to here would probably mean an extra 30 USD of shipping, which in addition to the exorbitant price of 8 USD is kind of ridiculous for a few centimeters of plastic and milimeter-thick metal, but... that's life I guess.

Comment: Anyway, suggest replacing the link with [this one](https://e-itx.com/2-54mm-to-2-0mm-pitch-pin-header-adapter-cable-for-pc-serial-port-3-inch-length/) - the actual seller offering the cable, rather than Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if there are 2 mm pitch unshrouded female plugs, then the answer is: yes.

For example:

- Hirose A4B: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/hirose-electric-co-ltd/A4B-2S-2C/141216
- Marwin M22: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/harwin-inc/M22-3010200/2264304

Comment: I asked "how", the answer can't be "yes" :-P ...   but I do see where you're going with this. Care to rephrase?

Comment: " Care to rephrase?"  On the contrary, care to answer my question ("What do you mean by "narrower"? "), so we know what you're actually asking, instead of trying to guess what you're thinking?